# How would I loop through a dataset and find the position of all missing values?

Tags: r, for-loop, missing-data

I have read in a dataset via a csv file and I am trying to loop through the whole dataset by rows to find the index position of each missing value. At the minute I have the following...

```
sum_of_missing <- function(x){sum(is.na(x))}
missing_data <- apply(data,1,sum_of_missing)
```

But would love to do this using a for loop to make it cleaner and to avoid hard coding the index positions in at others parts of code. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: It would be great if you can include parts of your input and desired output. Would be a lot easier.

Comment: do you overall just want to know the number of NAs in the whole dataset? This could be done with: sum(is.na(df))

Comment: @stat0007 No I really would like to find the positions of the NAs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for loop and hard coding

```
a_vector = c(3,5,6,7,NA,45,NA,56)
which(is.na(a_vector))

# [1] 5 7
```

Comment: Yes I tried that but the dataset is very large though with 12,000 observations. Would this still be clean enough to use @RiteshPorwal?

Comment: @ Jordan You can make a function for the code provided and apply to every row as you did with your code. I am sure that this is the quickest way.